# How to get the Page Number of the Current Page in Single Post Pagination

Tags: php, pagination

Let's say I have "Single Post" that is split by `<!--nextpage-->` pagination. And there are total of 50 Pages.

So a user is browsing on that post and he is at page 25. I want the Post to Display which Page he is at.

So it just shows **Page Number : 25**

If the question isn't clear you can comment requesting for more details and I will edit the question to elaborate it even more. But I guess it's not that hard to interpret this question.

Thanks for Helping out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your single page, you could try using the global `$page` variable.

Another alternative would be to try fetching the query `page` variable, with e.g.:

```
$wpse_current_page = (int) get_query_var( 'page' );

if( $wpse_current_page > 0 ) {
    printf( 
        __( 'Page Number: %d', 'wpse-theme-slug' ), 
        (int) $wpse_current_page  
    );
}
```

on your single page.